# If & else statement to change submit button text in _form.html.erb - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, control-flow

could one kindly advise me how this is written correctly:

file: views/adverts/_form.html.erb

```
  <% if action: "new" %>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Post Job' %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Update Job' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Would suggest checking `f.object.persisted?`. `action_name == 'new'` will return false if validation fails on create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`action_name`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActionController%2FBase%3Aaction_name). Also, instead of `if/else` use ternary operator (oneliner):

```
f.button :submit, action_name == 'new' ? 'Post Job' : 'Update Job'
```

or even shorter:

```
<%= f.submit action_name == 'new' ? 'Post Job' : 'Update Job'%>
```